# Add method for Double Linked List (Bubble Sort )

Tags: java, list, addition, bubble-sort

Hello I have a problem executing a bubble sort on my double linked list. The bubble sort works on different list types so I am assuming that it is correct. However when I use it on my double linked list I end up with an unsorted mess and duplicate nodes. I sort using an add and remove method in the double linked list class, so I think one or both must be wrong. Anyway here is my code and any help would be much appreciated.

My add method, I traverse the list either from head or tail depending on the value of index

```
public void my_add_element(int index, T element) throws myException{
    if(index <= num_items && index > -1)
    {
        if (index == num_items){
            myNode<T> nodeAtEnd = new myNode<T>(element);
            nodeAtEnd.setLeft(tail); 
            nodeAtEnd.setRight(null);
            if(tail != null)
                tail.setRight(nodeAtEnd); //link the list

            tail = nodeAtEnd; //now the tail is the new node i added

            if(head == null)       // if the list has no elements then set the head
                head = nodeAtEnd;

            num_items++;
        }
        else
        {
            myNode<T> current;
            myNode<T> nodeToInsert =  new myNode<T>(element);
            if(index <= Math.round(num_items/2))
            {
                current = this.head;
                for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                {
                    current = current.getRight();
                }
                if(current.getLeft() == null)
                {
                    this.head = nodeToInsert;
                    nodeToInsert.setRight(current);
                    current.setLeft(nodeToInsert);
                    num_items++;
                }
                else
                {
                    current.getLeft().setRight(nodeToInsert);
                    nodeToInsert.setLeft(current.getLeft());
                    nodeToInsert.setRight(current);
                    current.setLeft(nodeToInsert);
                    num_items++;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                current = this.tail;
                for(int i = 0; i < (num_items-(index+1)); i++)
                {
                    current = current.getLeft();
                }
                current.getLeft().setRight(nodeToInsert);
                nodeToInsert.setLeft(current.getLeft());
                nodeToInsert.setRight(current);
                current.setLeft(nodeToInsert);
                num_items++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        throw new myException("Invalid Index. The ADT does not have such an Index Position");   

}
```

My remove method, same again

```
public void my_remove_element(int index) throws myException{
    if(index < num_items)
    {
        myNode<T> current;
        if(index <= Math.round(num_items/2))
        {
            current = this.head;
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                current = current.getRight();
            }
            if(current.getLeft() == null)
                this.head = current.getRight();
            else
            {
                current.getRight().setLeft(current.getLeft());
                current.getLeft().setRight(current.getRight());
            }
            num_items--;
        }
        else
        {
            current = this.tail;
            for(int i = 0; i < (num_items-(index+1)); i++)
            {
                current = current.getLeft();
            }
            if(current.getRight() == null)
                this.tail = current.getLeft();
            else
            {
                current.getRight().setLeft(current.getLeft());
                current.getLeft().setRight(current.getRight());
            }
            num_items--;
        }
    }
    //2.2. If the index is a wrong one
    else
        throw new myException("Invalid Index. The ADT does not have such an Index Position");   
}
```

And my bubble sort, items is a list that can be a few different types of list, e.g. arrayList, linkedList, doubleLinkedList. The bubble sort works for arrayList and LinkedList.

```
public void bubble_sort(){
    for (int i = 0; i < items.my_get_length()-1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ((items.my_get_length() - 1) - i); j++)
        {
            if (items.my_get_element(j+1).smaller(items.my_get_element(j))) {
                items.my_add_element(j+2, items.my_get_element(j));
                items.my_remove_element(j);
            }
        }
}
```

items contains a list of football player details (name, goals scored).
this is the list I use.

Name : Rooney, Goals : 30
Name : Ibrahimovic, Goals : 46
Name : Messi, Goals : 80
Name : Aguero, Goals : 21
Name : Ronaldo, Goals : 89
Name : Muller, Goals : 33
Name : Lewandowski, Goals : 30

And this is what it looks like after the bubble sort

Name : Ibrahimovic, Goals : 46
Name : Messi, Goals : 80
Name : Ibrahimovic, Goals : 46
Name : Ibrahimovic, Goals : 46
Name : Lewandowski, Goals : 30
Name : Rooney, Goals : 30
Name : Aguero, Goals : 21

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Hello all I figured it out. My remove method was not updating pointers in the case of index being 0 or = to num_items